# How to preserve double quotes in $@ in a shell script?

Tags: shell

Let's say I have a really simple shell script 'foo':

```
  #!/bin/sh
  echo $@
```

If I invoke it like so:

```
  foo 1 2 3
```

It happily prints:

```
  1 2 3
```

However, let's say one of my arguments is double-quote enclosed and contains whitespace:

```
  foo 1 "this arg has whitespace" 3
```

foo happily prints:

```
  1 this arg has whitespace 3
```

The double-quotes have been stripped! I know shell thinks its doing me a favor, but... I would like to get at the original version of the arguments, unmolested by shell's interpretation. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 10):

First, you probably want quoted version of `$@`, i.e. `"$@"`. To feel the difference, try putting more than one space inside the string.

Second, quotes are element of shell's syntax -- it doesn't do you a favor. To preserve them, you need to escape them. Examples:

```
foo 1 "\"this arg has whitespace\"" 3

foo 1 '"this arg has whitespace"' 3
```

Comment: More on `"$@"` and how the quotes mean to quote what's inside of it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41595/21401

Answer (score 5):

Double quote $@:

```
#!/bin/sh
for ARG in "$@"
do
    echo $ARG
done
```

Then:

```
foo 1 "this arg has whitespace" 3
```

will give you:

```
1
this arg has whitespace
3
```

Comment: And then one can use `IFS` to avoid quoting hell demonstrated in other answers if one wants to do anything useful with such parameters....

Answer (score 5):

What i'd do is to quote all the arguments received with spaces that might help your case.

```
for x in "${@}" ; do
    # try to figure out if quoting was required for the $x
    if [[ "$x" != "${x%[[:space:]]*}" ]]; then
        x="\""$x"\""
    fi
    echo $x
    _args=$_args" "$x
done

echo "All Cmd Args are: $_args"
```

Comment: `"argument with spaces"` prints the exact same input. `"argument"` prints without double quotes. But this works the best

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the quotes:

```
foo 1 "\"this arg has whitespace\"" 3
```

or (more simply)

```
foo 1 '"this arg has whitespace"' 3
```

You need to quote the double quotes to make sure that the shell doesn't remove them when parsing word arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose you are in a more rigid set-up and you CANNOT change your command line, and make it more "friendly" by escaping the double quotes. For example:

```
example_script.sh argument_without_quotes "argument with quotes i cannot escape"
```

First consider that inside your script you can't tell if an argument is passed with or without quotes, because the shell strips them.

So what you can possibly do is **rebuilding double quotes for arguments containing whitespaces**

This example rebuilds the whole command line, double-quoting arguments that have white spaces

```
#!/bin/sh
#initialize the variable that will contain the whole argument string
argList=""
#iterate on each argument
for arg in "$@"
do
  #if an argument contains a white space, enclose it in double quotes and append to the list
  #otherwise simply append the argument to the list
  if echo $arg | grep -q " "; then
   argList="$argList \"$arg\""
  else
   argList="$argList $arg"
  fi
done

#remove a possible trailing space at the beginning of the list
argList=$(echo $argList | sed 's/^ *//')

#pass your argument list WITH QUOTES
echo "my_executable" $argList
#my_executable $argList
```

Note this limitation. If you run this example

```
example_script.sh "argument with spaces" argument_without_spaces "argument_doublequoted_but_without_spaces"
```

you will get this output

```
my_executable "argument with spaces" argument_without_spaces argument_doublequoted_but_without_spaces
```

Note the last argument: since it had no spaces, it has not been enclosed again in double quotes, but this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable method that I've found to do this is to leverage the logic that's built into the shell for "xtrace". This is a subsystem that's turned on via `set -x` which will print every command that's run by the shell. If we turn on xtrace then run a command that does nothing (`true`) with the same arguments, the shell (most shells...) will quote the arguments for us.

```
show_quoted() {
  (
    # use > as the xtrace prefix (this is the default)
    PS4='+'
    exec 2>&1  # send the xtrace (on stderr, 2) to stdout (1) for processing
    # turn on xtrace -- all commands are printed, with $PS4 as a prefix
    set -x
    # `true` is the command that does nothing, successfully
    true "$@"
  ) |
    sed '
      # remove the xtrace prefix -- any number of + characters
      s/^+*//
      # hide the "true" command
      s/^true //
    '
}
```

Same thing, but with a normal amount of comments:

```
show_quoted() {
  (
    PS4='+'  # reset to default
    exec 2>&1  # send xtrace to stdout
    set -x
    true "$@"
  ) | sed 's/^+*true //'  # remove the xtrace prefix
}
```

Here's my test results: (these vary a bit but are all valid)

```
$ sh show_quoted.sh 1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' "she said: 'bye'"
1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' 'she said: '\''bye'\'''

$ bash show_quoted.sh 1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' "she said: 'bye'"
1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' 'she said: '\''bye'\'''

$ zsh show_quoted.sh 1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' "she said: 'bye'"
1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' 'she said: '\''bye'\'

$ busybox sh show_quoted.sh 1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' "she said: 'bye'"
1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' 'she said: '"'"'bye'"'"
```

These shells (below) weren't up to the task however. To be fair, the toybox shell is "80% done".

```
$ dash show_quoted.sh 1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' "she said: 'bye'"
1 2 3 he said: "hi" she said: 'bye'

$ ./toybox sh show_quoted.sh 1 '2 3' 'he said: "hi"' "she said: 'bye'"
"$@"
```