# run bash command in new shell and stay in new shell after this command executes

Tags: bash, shell, command

I've got a problem. I'm searching for long time for this answer - how can I run command in new bash shell and stay in this NEW shell after this commands executes. So for example:

```
bash -c "export PS1='> ' && ls"
```

will make new shell, export PS1, list directories and ... will exit to my current shell. I want to stay in the new one.

Comment: can you explain us what you're trying to achieve. Maybe there're other way to do it.

Comment: @dimba I can't speak for danilo, but in my case I'm trying to ssh into my web server, cd into the app directory, and open a rails console for that app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke bash, run commands inside new shell, then give control back to user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-new-shell-then-give-control-back-to-user)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can achieve something similar by *abusing* the `--rcfile` option:

```
bash --rcfile <(echo "export PS1='> ' && ls")
```

From [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> --rcfile file
>
> > Execute commands from file instead of the system wide initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the standard  personal  initialization  file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive

Comment: thx vm!! and I was able to use my `.bashrc` file as base this way! `bash --rcfile <(echo "source "$HOME/.bashrc";export PS1='> ' && ls")`

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the case where the initial set of command is static and contain multiple commands, it is usually easier to use `here documents` to pass the initial commands, instead of constructing a script with series of echo commands.

This approach helps when the commands contain quotes, or various expansions. With the quoted here-documents (the `3<<'__INIT__' ... '__INIT__'`) variant, no expansion of the here document text is performed, eliminating the need to quote specific part of the commands.

Instead of

```
bash --rcfile <(echo "export PS1='> ' && ls && command1 && command2")
```

Use

```
bash --rcfile /dev/fd/3 3<<'__INIT__'
export PS1='> '
ls
command1
command2
__INIT__
```

Answer (score -1):

The lazy one:

```
bash -c "export PS1='> ' && ls; bash"
```

Comment: This starts another shell, but doesn't respect the new prompt.

Comment: For 5.0.3, I remained in the shell, and this gave me the `ls` but the `PS1` part didn't work for me.