# Make bash run a command right after it starts and then stay in this session?

Tags: bash

I need to run the command right after the bash starts and then stay in the session.
I was expecting something like that would work `bash && cd ~/Work`, but, apparentely, it would run the second command in the initial session, not the one I'm starting.

I've found this [run bash command in new shell and stay in new shell after this command executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192575/run-bash-command-in-new-shell-and-stay-in-new-shell-after-this-command-executes) thread, but running `bash --rcfile` doesn't work for me, because I still need the rcfile to be loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke bash, run commands inside new shell, then give control back to user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-new-shell-then-give-control-back-to-user)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still use `--rcfile`, you just need to include the sourcing of the default rc file in your command list:

```
bash --rcfile <(echo ". ~/.bashrc && cd ~/Work")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But what does the first dot before the ~/ mean?

Comment: `.` means the same as `source`.  More information is in the `bash` man page.