# Enter to unix shell with specific working directory

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I want to accomplish this:

```
[zsh]$ pwd
/home/user
*[zsh]$ bash # enter to a bash shell at the same time as `cd ~/Desktop`.
[bash]$ pwd
/home/user/Desktop
[bash]$ exit
[zsh]$ pwd
**/home/user
```

I would like to know if there is any way to enter to the unix shell at the same time as changing a directory to some specific path. It's important that:

1. Line `*` is supposed to be a single-line command for entering a shell and changing a directory,
2. After exist from any new shell, it's expected to return to the latest location as it was before entering to the shell, see line `**`.

Comment: 2 . is a default behavior of the shells.

Comment: I knew that, please read the answers below then you will know why I've mentioned this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using subshells is also useful for changing the current working directory temporary:

```
% (cd ~/Desktop && bash)
```

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward answer consists in using a bash configuration file switching to the proper directory. By creating a file ~/.my_bashrc containing a single line:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

you can then just type:

```
bash --rcfile ~/.my_bashrc
```

in a terminal to open a new shell directly in the Desktop directory.

Of course you can add other commands in ~/.my_bashrc (aliases, etc.), like in any regular bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this.

```
cd /home/user/Desktop && bash
```

This will try to change your current directory to `/home/user/Desktop` and if it succeeds changes the shell to `bash` else throws error.

Comment: The second step will happen by default when you exit.

Comment: It won't. what if at [zsh] I'm at `/usr/local` in stead of `~`. It's obvious that your solution doesn't bring me back to `/usr/local` after exit from [bash].

Comment: Did you try `exit && cd -`

Comment: It should work but that's not an effective one. You can change only the line `*` on my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pushd` and `popd` commands:

```
pushd ~/Desktop && bash ; popd
```

`pushd` in this case is like "remember and cd" - it adds new directory to the top of directory stack, making it current directory. Next you start `bash` and *after* you exit bash, `popd` takes you back to the directory remembered by pushd.

EDIT: changed `&&` to `;` for better error handling, as pointed out in comment.

Comment: Only if `bash` exits successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think answer of @hchbaw is a bit tricky. I've just found a more effective solution from [run bash command in new shell and stay in new shell after this command executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192575/run-bash-command-in-new-shell-and-stay-in-new-shell-after-this-command-executes?noredirect=1&lq=1). In my case I can use:

```
bash --rcfile <(echo "cd ~/Desktop")
```