# Run shell command with "redirecting of an output from a subshell" statement within go

Tags: bash, go, command-line

According to [run bash command in new shell and stay in new shell after this command executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192575/run-bash-command-in-new-shell-and-stay-in-new-shell-after-this-command-executes), how can I run command:

```
bash --rcfile <(echo "export PS1='> ' && ls")
```

within golang? I've tried many combinations of `exec.Command()` but they did't work. For example:

```
exec.Command("bash", "--rcfile", `<("echo 'ls'")`)
```

I've also read this [os, os/exec: using redirection symbol '<' '>' failed](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11866), but I think maybe my case is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there - I think the confusion is you're using piping *to call bash*, which means you actually need to call bash *using bash*:

```
exec.Command("bash", "-c", `bash --rcfile <(echo "export PS1='> ' && ls")`)
```