# Execute a command in new interactive tcsh shell

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

How can I execute a pre-command in a new `tcsh` interactive shell?

Ex: For mimicking `bash -O globstar` in `tcsh` we can do `set globstar`

However, `tcsh -c 'set globstar'` won't work as it won't leave the interactive shell. Exits immediately after executing the command.

I need it to run a script on a remote machine where I **can not** modify any `rc` files

Assume the script is as below

```
      0 > cat run
      echo foo/**
```

With `bash` I can do the following

```
      0 > bash -O globstar run
      foo/ foo/bar foo/bar/foo foo/bar/foo/bar
```

I am looking for a `tcsh` equivalent, something like below (it obviously won't work as `tcsh` will not run my program)

```
       0 > tcsh -c 'set globstar' run
```

PS: I know `bash -c` is same as `tcsh -c`. I am looking for an equivalent of `bash -O` even if it is for limited options.

PS: This is simply `tcsh` version of the following question.

[run bash command in new shell and stay in new shell after this command executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192575/run-bash-command-in-new-shell-and-stay-in-new-shell-after-this-command-executes)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a script, you can set any options by simply adding `set option`, like you would in the startup file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh

set globstar

# .. your code ..
```

For a Makefile, the same thing should work as well:

```
SHELL=/bin/tcsh

all:
        set noglobstar
        set
```

Other tan this, there is no easy way to do this other than changing a startup file. As far as I can find in the manual page there is no switch to set an option on startup, and unfortunately tcsh doesn't allow changing the startup file location with a commandline argument, either.

To avoid changing individual user's startup files, you can put the changes in the system-wide `/etc/csh.cshrc`. From `tcsh(1)`:

```
   Startup and shutdown
       A login shell begins  by  executing  commands  from  the  system  files
       /etc/csh.cshrc  and  /etc/csh.login.   It  then  executes commands from
       files in  the  user's  home  directory:  first  ~/.tcshrc  (+)  or,  if
       ~/.tcshrc  is  not found, ~/.cshrc, then the contents of ~/.history (or
       the value of the histfile shell variable) are loaded into memory,  then
       ~/.login,  and  finally  ~/.cshdirs (or the value of the dirsfile shell
       variable) (+).  The shell may read  /etc/csh.login  before  instead  of
       after /etc/csh.cshrc, and ~/.login before instead of after ~/.tcshrc or
       ~/.cshrc and ~/.history, if so compiled; see the  version  shell  vari‐
       able. (+)

       Non-login  shells read only /etc/csh.cshrc and ~/.tcshrc or ~/.cshrc on
       startup.
```

Comment: Thanks @martin-tournoij. My requirement is slightly different. I have updated my question to make it more explicit. Thank you for taking time.

Comment: Is there a reason to not add `set globstar` to the script itself @Krishna? That is probably a better way even if something like `-O` would exist, because then the script will always run, no matter how you invoke it.

Comment: The reason is there is no script :p

The actual use case (analogous to the script case) is in the Makefile

We have a Makefile that uses `SHELL=tcsh`, which should be upgraded to use glob.

The simple trick in bash is to use `SHELL="bash -O"`

Comment: Well, you mentioned "script", @Krishna :-) Either way, you can just add `set globstar` to a Make target.

Comment: I have to add it to all make targets that way :)