# Start bash in certain directory from Windows

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to start Bash.exe in the "/mnt" directory.

The following command properly starts bash:

```
C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe
```

I have the following .bat file:

```
C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe -c "cd /mnt/"
```

Unfortunately, this does not do anything. The same applies to:

```
C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe --cd "/mnt/"
```

Comment: Disclaimer: even though there are very similar posts, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't use bash.exe, but, have you tried "\" ?

Comment: The formatting of the slashes is already correct in this example. If it were not, it should give an error that it can not find the path.

Comment: Do you have a .bash_profile or .bashrc file in your home directory?

Comment: No. I do not have a .bash_profile or .bashrc file in my /home directory, nor in any of it's subdirectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe -c "cd /mnt/ ; exec bash"
```

That starts a Bash process that cds to '/mnt/' and then replaces itself with a new (interactive) Bash process that is running in the '/mnt' directory.

The code above is only lightly tested, and may or may not meet your requirements.  For alternatives see [run bash command in new shell and stay in new shell after this command executes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7192575/4154375) and "Linked" pages from that.

Comment: This fully meets my requirements. I tested it and it works perfect. Great work.