# How not to terminate after carried out commands in bash

Tags: bash

After carrying out commands with "-c" option of bash, how can I make the terminal wait for input while preserving the environment?

Like `CMD /K ***` or `pwsh -NoExit -Command ***`.

Comment: This might help: [run bash command in new shell and stay in new shell after this command executes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7192575/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74094552/how-not-to-terminate-after-carried-out-commands-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment130821649_74094552) by [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus):

> You can achieve something similar by *abusing* the `--rcfile` option:
>
> ```
> bash --rcfile <(echo "export PS1='> ' && ls")
> ```
>
> From [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):
>
> > --rcfile file
> >
> > > Execute commands from file instead of the system wide initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the standard  personal  initialization  file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive

This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you!!

As an example of use, I use the following method to use the latest docker image with my preferred repository without building the image:

```bash
# Call bash in the container from bash
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:22.04 bash -c "bash --rcfile <(echo 'sed -i -E '\''s%^(deb(-src|)\s+)https?://(archive|security)\.ubuntu\.com/ubuntu/%\1http://mirrors.xtom.com/ubuntu/%'\'' /etc/apt/sources.list && apt update && FooBar=`date -uIs`')"
```

```
# ... from pwsh
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:22.04 bash -c "bash --rcfile <(echo 'sed -i -E '\''s%^(deb(-src|)\s+)https?://(archive|security)\.ubuntu\.com/ubuntu/%\1http://mirrors.xtom.com/ubuntu/%'\'' /etc/apt/sources.list && apt update && FooBar=``date -uIs``')"
```

---

```bash
# Call dash (BusyBox ash) in the container from bash
docker run --rm -it alpine:latest ash -c "ash -c 'export ENV=\$1;ash' -s <(echo 'sed -i -E '\''s%^https?://dl-cdn\.alpinelinux\.org/alpine/%https://ftp.udx.icscoe.jp/Linux/alpine/%'\'' /etc/apk/repositories && apk update && FooBar=`date -uIs`')"
```

```
# ... from pwsh
docker run --rm -it alpine:latest ash -c "ash -c 'export ENV=`$1;ash' -s <(echo 'sed -i -E '\''s%^https?://dl-cdn\.alpinelinux\.org/alpine/%https://ftp.udx.icscoe.jp/Linux/alpine/%'\'' /etc/apk/repositories && apk update && FooBar=``date -uIs``')"
```