# Launch interactive Bash shell in Ruby script, with initial command

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm working on an interactive Ruby script, which build and packages resources. In the middle of the process, I'd like to drop into an **interactive shell, but pre-`cd`'d into a specific working directory**, as well as with an explanatory message (CTRL-D to continue). The interactive bash + given initial command is what's problematic.

Per the answer for doing something like this in Bash, given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152028, I've tried

`system '/bin/bash', '--init-file', '<(echo "cd ~/src/devops; pwd")'`

However, bash runs interactively but **completely ignores the `'<(echo "cd ~/src/devops; pwd")'` section**.

Interestingly `system '/bin/bash', '--init-file` complains if no argument is given, but literally anything runs bash, but with no initial command.

**Note that (--rcfile instead of --init-file) has the same effect.*

Comment: You can just change the current working directory of the Ruby script before launching `bash`; the working directory is inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the working directory of the Ruby script first, so that `bash` inherits the correct working directory.

```
curr_dir = Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir("#{Dir.home}/src/devops")
system "/bin/bash"
Dir.chdir(curr_dir)   # Restore the original working directory if desired
```

Oh, this is probably far better (you can probably guess how little familiarity I have with Ruby):

```
system("/bin/bash", :chdir=>"#{Dir.home}/src/devops")
```

Comment: Aha! That works fine for what I'm needing. Thanks @chepner!