# VSCode: How to run a command after each terminal open?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

On Windows I have to run the command `start-ssh-agent.cmd` on each new terminal session I open. My development environment is VSCode, and I open a dozen new terminals each day. After each terminal open, I have to manually run this command.

Is there is a way to run this command on the terminal each time I open one ?

[image]

This may take the form of a VSCode extension, VSCode configuration (settings) or a Windows environment configuration.

Any idea?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The other answer are great but a little outdated.  You will get a warning in VSCode.  Here is what I'm doing in my `XXX.code-workspace` file on linux:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
      "BashWithStartup": {
        "path": "bash",
        "args": [
          "--init-file",
          "./terminal_startup.sh"
        ]
      }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "BashWithStartup"
```

Be sure to make sure your `terminal_startup.sh` script is executable:

```
chmod u+x terminal_startup.sh
```

Comment: Also as the other answer says, it's likely you want `source ~/.bashrc` in your `terminal_startup.sh` file.

Comment: And if you don't `chmod u+x terminal_startup.sh` it'll just silently skip the terminal_startup.sh script rather than erroring (there's probably a log with a message)

Answer (score 34):

On Linux systems you should use:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux"
```

On Windows and OSX:

```
terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows
```

and

```
terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx
```

respectively.

If you want to apply `shellArgs` setting on a per-workspace basis - you can, despite the fact that [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-and-security) says:

> The first time you open a workspace which defines any of these settings, VS Code will warn you and **subsequently always ignore the values** after that

At least version 1.42 of VSCode asks you something like:

> "This workspace wants to set `shellArgs`, do you want to allow it?"

[See issue 19758](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19758)

---

On Linux, if you are using `bash` (default for shell in VSCode), there are some subtleties:

1. ```
   "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["your_init_script.sh"]
   ```

   will execute the script and close terminal right away. To prevent this you'll have to end the script with `$SHELL` command.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "init"
   export PATH=$PATH:/xxx/yyy/zzz # or do whatever you want
   $SHELL
   ```

   But that way you end up in a **subshell**. Sometimes it's unacceptable [(Read 1)](https://serverfault.com/a/834344/562086) [(Read 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/how-to-invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-the-new-shell-and-then-give-control-bac).
2. ```
   "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["--init-file", "your_init_script.sh"]
   ```

   will leave you in the initial shell, but will not execute the `.bashrc` init file. So you may want to `source ~/.bashrc` inside `your_init_script.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   source ~/.bashrc
   echo "init"
   export PATH=$PATH:/xxx/yyy/zzz # or do whatever you want
   ```
3. And if you already have `some_init_script.sh` in a repository, and for some reason don't feel like adding `source ~/.bashrc` into it, you can use this:

   ```
   "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["--init-file", "your_init_script.sh"]
   ```

   *your_init_script.sh*:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   source ~/.bashrc
   source some_init_script.sh
   ```

   *some_init_script.sh*:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "init"
   export PATH=$PATH:/xxx/yyy/zzz # or do whatever you want
   ```

   ---

   *Outside of VSCode you can do without creating extra file. Like this*

   ```
   bash --init-file <(echo "source ~/.bashrc; source some_init_script.sh")
   ```

   *But I could not pass this string into `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux` - it needs to be split into array somehow. And none of the combinations I've tried worked.*

---

Also, you can open terminal at a specific folder:

```
terminal.integrated.cwd
```

Change env:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux"
"terminal.integrated.env.windows"
"terminal.integrated.env.osx"
```

And even change terminal to your liking with

```
terminal.integrated.shell.linux
terminal.integrated.shell.windows
terminal.integrated.shell.osx
```

Or

```
terminal.external.linuxExec
terminal.external.osxExec
terminal.external.windowsExec
```

Comment: Surely there has to be more to this answer? If you just set `shellArgs.linux` to a script, won't the shell just execute the script and exit?

Comment: After a little bit of digging found a better solution: `--init-file`. Updated the answer.
Also that may be helpful https://serverfault.com/questions/368054/run-an-interactive-bash-subshell-with-initial-commands-without-returning-to-the?newreg=627eeaeb1c9741c6944c3b83fa0db39d

Comment: Well, the man page says `Execute commands from file instead of the standard personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive`

Comment: @Hubro, you're right. That took me a while. But I think I've made it. Updated the answer.

Comment: Note that to add `["--init-file", "your_init_script.sh"]` in the settings ui (not the json) you need to add `--init-file` and `your_init_script.sh` as two separate items.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer.  Kudos to you!

Comment: `terminal.integrated.shellArgs` is now **deprecated** - see @Robert's answer below for a modern solution.

Comment: What I needed to see was the `.bashrc` file name. And with it, I could make the updates I needed.

Answer (score 33):

I actually found a pretty neat Linux solution for this. It should also work on Windows if you use a shell like Bash. I'm not sure if it's possible using vanilla CMD.

Add something like this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```bash
#
# Allow parent to initialize shell
#
# This is awesome for opening terminals in VSCode.
#
if [[ -n $ZSH_INIT_COMMAND ]]; then
    echo "Running: $ZSH_INIT_COMMAND"
    eval "$ZSH_INIT_COMMAND"
fi
```

Now, in your VSCode workspace setting, you can set an environment variable like this:

```js
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "ZSH_INIT_COMMAND": "source dev-environment-setup.sh"
}
```

Now the script "dev-environment-setup.sh" will be automatically sourced in all new VSCode terminal windows.

Comment: Really interesting! Thanks for sharing @Hubro

Comment: It looks nicer than my answer. But wouldn't it require editing `.bashrc` of every team member? And so require extra work, extra documentation, and can even introduce conflicts, if `ZSH_INIT_COMMAND` (or any name for that matter) already in use in someone's `.bashrc`.

Comment: @x00 Yes, but that's fine. The only part of this that is shared with the team is the dev session setup script. Everything else is local to my PC. My team members can choose to source the script manually, or they can replicate my setup if they want.

Comment: This is so elegant! Thanks man!

Comment: This is the only answer that works with zsh (which has no `--init-file` equivalent) AND doesn't initiate a sub-shell. Very nice solution, other than the downside mentioned by x00 in the earlier comment.

Comment: @jeff-h this seems to work for me: `"args": [ "-c", "source ${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/terminal/zsh-init.sh; zsh" ]`

Answer (score 20):

You can do the following:

```json
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["start-ssh-agent.cmd"]
```

Modified from: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_shell-arguments

Comment: use /K command to process command as an immediate command in terminal such as set CLASSPATH, `["/K", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"]`

Comment: This solution is now deprecated. The actual solution in current VSCode versions is to use Automation Profiles, like mentioned in this thread by Robert in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70029070/3408335

Answer (score 4):

I use the following for powershell on Windows:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-NoExit",
        "-Command", "conda activate ./env"
    ]
}
```

Comment: No longer works; key is now `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71512662.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using the wonderful [cmder](https://cmder.net/), you'll need something akin to the following in your `settings.json`

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "CMDER_ROOT": "C:\\path\\to\\cmder"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k",
        "%CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.cmd"
    ],
}
```

And then you can add any aliases into the `user_aliases.cmd` file that should already exist in `%CMDER_ROOT%\\config\\user_aliases.cmd`

Answer (score 3):

After the April 2021 update the configuration structure has been changed.
Check [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles).
There's a distinction even between terminal instances. To run a file on Windows:

**PowerShell**

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "My PowerShell": {
      "path": "pwsh.exe",
      "args": ["-noexit", "-file", "${env:APPDATA}PowerShellmy-init-script.ps1"]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "My PowerShell"
}
```

**Command Prompt**

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "cmder": {
      "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
      "args": ["/K", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.cmd"]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "cmder"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use PowerShell you can add a PowerShell Script to your your profile in which you can execute what you want. Each development environment has 4 Profiles, stored in $Profile:

- AllUsersAllHosts
- AllUsersCurrentHost
- CurrentUserAllHosts
- CurrentUserCurrentHost

Eg create a profile in VSCode with

```
code $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
```

[Some more details](https://patrickwahlmueller.wordpress.com/2019/01/31/powershell-profile/)

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, the following worked for me on OSX:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [
    "-l",
    "-c",
    "source script.sh; bash"
],
```

For context, I'm using this with a jupyter notebook to set environment variables that cannot simply be defined using `terminal.integrated.env.osx`

Answer (score 1):

I did this for accessing `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for 2022`:

```bash
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "x64 Native": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [
                "/K",
                "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat",
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "x64 Native",
}
```