# How to execute a script every time the integrated terminal opens up in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have one script `set_path.bat` that adds a few custom paths to `PATH` variable.

What I want is:
That script should get executed every time I open the integrated terminal inside `VSCode`

**OR**

How can a few custom paths be appended to `PATH` variable every time I open up the integrated terminal?

I had a look at `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` option and tried something like 
`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe set_path.bat",`
But did not work.

I also had a look at `"terminal.integrated.env.windows"` and tried to set something like this

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PATH": "SOME_PATHS; %PATH%" 
}
```

But it had a problem resolving `%PATH%` (as expected) and because of that, the `PATH` variable just had the customized path. ( I need the default paths in the `PATH` as well! )

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635168/vscode-how-to-run-a-command-after-each-terminal-open helpful?

Comment: Yeah, that's helpful. In fact, this is the exact duplicate of that question. Voting to close the question. Thanks!

Comment: You can just delete your question, can't you?