# Mutliple SSH connections inside Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

Is it possible that I can use multiple SSH connections inside Visual Studio Code? I have created 8 different SSH Targets. I think a good solution could be that inside the same window I only have to switch the terminal from one target to the next target.

Also, I have created a workspace. code-workspace file in which I have opened different network drives together as one workspace. The point is if I open one SSH target it would be opened inside a new window and if not, the workspace gets closed. Is it possible to combine both solutions?

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The remote SSH capability added to VSCode (and [documented here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)) is only valid for one remote SSH connection at a time (seen in the lower-left corner)

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/remote/ssh/ssh-statusbar.png]

If you want to develop locally, but still have multiple terminals, each one with their own SSH connection, you would need to:

- [declare multiple terminals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44592824/6309)
- configure them to launch their own ssh command when starting their session ([using `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.<OS>`":](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45635168/6309) )

Comment: Is it possible to use VSCode to do remote SSH where the destination IP & PORT are dynamic. I have a requirement to connect to remote serverB via serverA. When I login to serverA, I am redirected to serverB based on sshd_configs on serverA. when I do ssh via cmd line it goes fine to serverB. But VSCode is not able to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: @ArunChandramouli I don't know if this is possible. I will follow your issue (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6634)