# Auto run a command when terminal opens in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh

I'd like to run the command *reload -b* whenever a terminal opens in Visual Studio Code on a Mac. The accepted answer [to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45635875/266435) gives a deprecated warning.

I've set my default profile (ZSH) and configured it as suggested in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles), but the command still doesn't run.

Any help is much appreciated - thanks

My `settings.json` looks like:

```
   "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "zsh (login)": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "args": [
                "reload -b"
            ]
        }
    },
```