# Command executes after I open new bash terminal in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Somehow, at some point, I set the command to execute when a new terminal in vscode is opened and I can't figure out where it is set. I have checked vscode settings.json (global and local) with no luck. This command is not executed when starting a new bash, but after it is initialized, that is, I see the command as below:

```bash
norbert@DESKTOP-2E05HS2:/mnt/c/Users/Norbert/Desktop$ conda activate user
```

When I type `bash` in the console to open a new shell, this command is not executed. This only happens when I open a new terminal via vscode.

Any ideas?

BR
Norbert

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635168/vscode-how-to-run-a-command-after-each-terminal-open) help?

Comment: Python extension activates the virt env when you open a terminal

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, unfortunately, it is not it. The command suggested in the link is deprecated for `"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux"`, but it does not help whether I leave it empty or remove it altogether.
@rioV8, I'll check it, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I disabled the python extension and that **solves** the problem for me. Now I need to figure out what settings to change. Thank you for your help.

Comment: select a Python interpreter that is not in a virt env

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles

Comment: Yes this probably just means that in your folder/project you have selected the conda environment named `user` as the python environment. It is normal (and appropriate) to activate that environment when you start a terminal - nothing to worry about.