# asdf-vm using a .local version of .tool-versions (.tool-versions.local)

Tags: asdf-vm

Usage case:
a git repo for an app contains a .tool-versions file with all the tooling required to the app or to deploy it.

me as a user, or another user might have a preference for additional tooling for this particular project as would rather not have it installed/shimmed as a 'global' but just have it consumed within the repository for the app.

Ideally I am looking for .tool-versions.local where I can add my own tooling alongside the tooling.
Is anyone here using a similar workflow, and what is your implementation like?

I've looked into using .envrc and .envrc.local to perform tasks like:

```
asdf plugin add myplugin
asdf install myplugin latest
asdf local myplugin latest
```

the problem here is that the last `asdf local...` will modify the .tool-versions file.
I really want to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

The feature doesn't currently exist within asdf, but you *can* do it yourself by overriding cd. Plop the following in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

```bash
cd() {
  ... # Your other commands

  if [ -f '.tool-versions.local' ]; then
    export ASDF_DEFAULT_TOOL_VERSIONS_FILENAME='.tool-versions.local'
  else
    export ASDF_DEFAULT_TOOL_VERSIONS_FILENAME='.tool-versions'
  fi
}
```

This way, `asdf local` should override `.tool-versions.local` if it exists. You may want to add this code to `pushd` and `popd`, if you use those builtins as well.

One downside to this approach is that sometimes, in some situations, for some editors, this code may not be ran when you open a new terminal. For VSCode, you can [configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635168/vscode-how-to-run-a-command-after-each-terminal-open) to do so. Other popular editors should have a similar configuration as well.