# docker exec bash behaves weirdly

Tags: bash, docker

When I do:

> docker exec -ti myContainer /bin/bash

I have a new bash terminal on running container myContainer.

Now when I write

> docker exec -ti lescompanions /bin/bash -c "echo youpi"

docker only outputs **youpi** and returns with no interactive terminal created. I was actually expecting docker to create the terminal and run **echo youpi** within the newly created terminal.

Where am I wrong?

---- EDIT ----

Now how shall I run **echo youpi** in the new terminal on the existing container and not have the terminal return to the host after the execution of **echo youpi**?

Comment: that's the way `bash -c 'whatever'` **always** works, even without docker: It runs the script passed to `-c`, then it exits.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask how to make bash do this *in general*, factoring Docker out of the question? Scoping it as a Docker question adds no value, when the real problem is generic to bash and can be reproduced without Docker even being installed.

Comment: so in the docker case, is there a way to create a new container terminal, have it execute a command, and hope the new terminal stays alive afterwards?

Comment: What **exactly** are you asking? Do you want the copy of `bash` to persist after it runs the initial command? (This is a reasonable request, and I'm certain we already have Q&A covering it outside the scope of `docker`). Do you want the TTY created by Docker to be available for other commands even after the initial command exits? (If so, err, *why*? What value is there to that?)

Comment: It sounds like what you want, for instance, is already answered in the preexisting question [Invoke bash, run commands inside new shell, then give control back to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-new-shell-then-give-control-back-to-user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker exec` takes a command to run a process inside the container while the `-it` flag attaches an interactive session against that process.

Your session will only live as long as the command given to `exec`

As others have mentioned the command `/bin/bash -c "echo youpi"` simply uses bash to run the command `echo "echo youpi"` and terminates, hence your terminal session terminates also.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong, it's just how bash works. I've checked it on my Ubuntu (without Docker):

```
$ /bin/bash
(no output, bash instance running)

$ /bin/bash -c "echo youpi"
youpi
(bash finished)
```

Comment: All right. So is there a way to have **echo youpi** executed into my newly created terminal AND WITHOUT RETURNING?

Comment: Remove `-c "echo youpi"` and it will stay running

Comment: Sure, but I would like to both create the new terminal on the container AND have it execute a command AND have the new terminal stay alive afterwards. Another way to put it is that I would like the host to execute a command in a container terminal...

Comment: Most probably it's not what you want but a workaround would be: bash -c "echo youpi && read x". Of course instead of "read x" you can do sleep or execute another command.

Answer (score 0):

`echo youpi` is a command that is run inside the container. The `echo` command prints the arguments given to it, which is `youpi` in this case, and that is also what you see.

Comment: All right, now how shall I keep my new container terminal running rather than bash returning to the host after bash's execution?

Comment: Try `-c "echo youpi && /bin/bash" `

Comment: `-c "echo youpi && exec /bin/bash -li"`, rather. Otherwise you have two separate copies of bash in memory; the `exec` tells the current copy to replace itself.