# Preventing tmux session created by systemd from automatically terminating on Ctrl+C

Tags: linux, systemd, tmux, sigterm

Since a few days I'm successfully running the new *Minecraft Bedrock Edition* dedicated server on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS home server. Because it should be available 24/7 and automatically startup after boot I created a **systemd** service for a detached **tmux** session:

**tmux.minecraftserver.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=tmux minecraft_server detached

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/mine/minecraftserver
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new -s minecraftserver -d "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. /home/mine/minecraftser$
User=mine

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Everything works as expected but there's one tiny thing that keeps bugging me:

How can I prevent *tmux* from terminating it's whole session when I press `Ctrl+C` ?
I just want to terminate the Minecraft server process **itself** instead of the whole *tmux* session. When starting the server from the command line in a manually created tmux session this **does** work (session stays alive) but not when the session was brought up by *systemd*.

Comment: I can name lots of reasons to run services in tmux. For example, some may have an admin console to attach to. I think that this question is legitimate and important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I as able to solve this by using systemd's `ExecStartPost` and tmux's `send-keys` like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=tmux minecraft_server detached

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/mine/minecraftserver
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new -d -s minecraftserver
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/tmux send-keys -t minecraftserver "cd /home/mine/minecraftserver/" Enter "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server" Enter

User=mine

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

> When starting the server from the command line in a manually created tmux session this **does** work (session stays alive) but not when the session was brought up by *systemd*.

The difference between these situations is actually unrelated to systemd. In one case, you’re starting the server from a shell within the tmux session, and when the server terminates, control returns to the shell. In the other case, you’re starting the server directly within the tmux session, and when it terminates there’s no shell to return to, so the tmux session also dies.

tmux has an option to keep the session alive after the process inside it dies (look for `remain-on-exit` in the manpage), but that’s probably not what you want: you want to be able to return to an interactive shell, to restart the server, investigate why it died, or perform maintenance tasks, for example. So it’s probably better to change your command to this:

```
'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. /home/mine/minecraftserver/…; exec bash'
```

That is, first run the server, and then, after it terminates, replace the process (the shell which tmux implicitly spawns to run the command, but which will then exit) with another, interactive shell. (For some other ways to get an interactive shell after the command exits, see e. g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7120426/1420237) – but note that the `<(echo commands)` syntax suggested in the top answer is not available in systemd unit files.)

Comment: This is also a nice solution.

Comment: ctrl+c with this approach still exits the tmux session. If the app closes in other ways, then it certainly keeps it open with the bash terminal instead.