# Docker run bash --init-file

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to create an alias to help debug my docker containers.

I discovered bash [accepts a `--init-file`](https://serverfault.com/a/586272/28684) option which ought to let us run some commands before passing over to interactive mode.

So I thought I could do

```
docker-bash() {
  docker run --rm -it "$1" bash --init-file <(echo "ls; pwd")
}
```

But those commands don't appear to be running:

```
 % docker-bash c7460dfcab50
root@9c6f64a9db8c:/#
```

Is it an escaping issue or.. what's going on?

```
bash --init-file <(echo "ls; pwd")
```

Alone in a terminal on my host machine works as expected (runs the command starts a new bash instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In points:

- The `<(...)` is a bash extension [process subtitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).
- From the manual above: `Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.`.
- The process substitution works like this:

  - bash creates a fifo in `/tmp` or creates a new file descriptor in `/dev/fd`.
  - The filename, either the `/tmp/.something` or `/dev/fd/<number>` is substituted for `<(...)` when command is executed.
  - So for example `echo <(echo 1)` outputs `/dev/fd/63`.
- Docker works by creating a new environment that is separated from the host. That means that:

  - Processes inside docker do not inherit file descriptors from the host process:

    - So `/dev/fd/*` files are not inherited.
  - Processes inside docker are accessing isolated filesystem tree.

    - So processes can't access `/tmp/*` files from the host.
- So summarizing `docker run -ti --rm alpine cat <(echo 1)` will not work, because the filename substituted by `<(...)` is not available from docker environment.

An easy workaround would be to just:

```
docker run -ti --rm alpine sh -c 'ls; pwd; exec sh'
```

Or use a temporary file:

```
echo "ls; pwd" > /tmp/tempfile
docker run -v /tmp/tempfile:/tmp/tempfile bash bash --init-file /tmp/tempfile
```

Comment: I don't think that's strictly equivalent, is it? I should have specified what I really want to do is define an alias or two and `exec sh` will start another new shell so they'll be lost :-(

Comment: Right, exactly. You can always do a temporary file. `echo something > tempfile; docker run ... -v tempfile:/tmp/tempfile bash --init-file /tmp/tempfile`. This is very similar problem to passing `alias` or anything else when doing `ssh`.

Comment: It took a while to realize the solution is underneath, maybe you could combine your answers? As your explanation is really valuable, but not solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For my use-case I wanted to set an `alias` which won't persist if we re-exec the shell. However, aliases can be written to `~/.bashrc` which will be reloaded on the subsequent exec. Ergo,

```
docker-bash() {
  docker run --rm -it "$1" bash -c $'set -o xtrace; echo "alias ll=\'ls -lAhtrF --color=always\'" >> ~/.bashrc; exec "$0"'
}
```

Works. `--rm` should clean up any files we create anyway if I understand properly how docker works.

Or perhaps this is a nicer way to write it:

```
docker-bash() {
read -r -d '' BASHRC << EOM
alias ll='ls -lAhtrF --color=always'
EOM
docker run --rm -it "$1" bash -c "echo \"$BASHRC\" >> ~/.bashrc; exec \"\$0\""
}
```