# How to properly escape script to be passed into for `docker run /bin/bash --init-file`

Tags: bash, docker

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814742/docker-run-bash-init-file) is close, but uses a temp-file with volume where I want the `echo "cd..."` command to run in the init-script context (inside the container, where /bin/bash is executed).

I feel like I need to further escape something to defer execution, but I'm stuck.

This is more about understanding bash and where I've gone wrong, but the ultimate goal is nothing more than to launch bash inside an interactive container, and leave the user in the directory of choice (executing 'cd ...' inside the session via .profile, by appending to it using init-file [or has .profile been read at that point, making this useless]).

Why does this result in all the single-quotes see in the resulting code below?

```sh
dockerCmds="/bin/bash --init-file="$setupCmd" -c \"\$SHELL\""

docker run -it --rm \
    --user docker \
    --entrypoint "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/scripts/entrypoint.sh" \
    -e CI_PROJECT_DIR \
    -v ${PWD}:$CI_PROJECT_DIR \
    myImage \
    $dockerCmds;

# Runs, but the "cd /home/docker/src" command isn't being appended to so I'm left in bash, but .profile isn't modified

/home/docker/.profile
docker run -it --rm \
  --user docker \
  --entrypoint /home/docker/src/scripts/entrypoint.sh \
  -e CI_PROJECT_DIR \
  -v ~/myApp:/home/docker/src \
  myImage \
  /bin/bash '--init-file=<(echo' '"cd' '$CI_PROJECT_DIR">>/home/docker/.profile)' -c '"$SHELL"';
```

If I quote $dockerCmds, I get an error making me think I'm closer to passing init-file

Here's how I can do it with a temp file (to hopefully further clarify my intent):

```sh
tempBashRc=$(mktemp /tmp/myImage-bashrc.XXXXXXXXX)
CID=$(docker create myImage)
docker cp ${CID}:/home/docker/.bashrc $tempBashRc
docker rm ${CID}
printf "\ncd $CI_PROJECT_DIR;\n" >> $tempBashRc
dockerCmds="/bin/bash";
```

Comment: Read ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `'--init-file=<(` sorry, it does not work that way. How is the `<(...)` process substitution going to be transferred inside docker context? I would recommend to please research what is word splitting and how it works. Then re-read some good docker introduction - how it works, what is chroot and what is allowed for processes to access. Then  what is `<(..)` process substitution and how it works.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your Dockerfile?  This use of `--entrypoint` seems overcomplicated and there's probably a way to restructure the Dockerfile to avoid it.  It'd also help to understand what command the container should actually run in the end (presumably something more useful than a bare shell).

Comment: KamilCuk: that is the entire point. I want it to execute in the docker context so it has no concern with the context of the outer script. I cannot figure out how to escape it in though so that it's deferred to the inner context.

Comment: David Maze: I am AFK but will update the question with a gist for the docker file shortly. I wouldn't be the least bit surprise if I have over complicated it, getting lost in the mess and I would welcome an elegant solution. I have been active on bash since the days of red hat one, but I've never considered myself a sysadmin or bash expert.