# How to drop into docker bash and navigate to the log directory in one command

Tags: bash, docker

Currently, I drop into docker bash using the command `docker exec -it jboss /bin/bash` and then navigate to the log directory `cd /blah/blah/blah/logs/` so I can tail different logs that are dumped there.

If I set up an alias to do one command after the other using `&&` or `;` then it doesn't work because (I assume) that bash is running the second `cd` command inside the original shell rather than the new docker bash I just dropped into.

I am also aware that docker has a built in log command to do this, but there are multiple different log files that I want to tail.

I tried to utilize the `--rcfile` trick like `docker exec -it jboss /bin/bash --rcfile <(echo 'ls')` but wasn't able to figure it out: [How to invoke bash, run commands inside the new shell, and then give control back to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/how-to-invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-the-new-shell-and-then-give-control-bac)

Has anyone accomplished something like this in the past? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read `docker exec --help`

Comment: @KamilCuk okay, not much info there...  -d, -e and -u don't really help here from what I am seeing, and I am currently trying to drop into interactive with -i. Are you suggesting using the [ARG...] ? I've tested trying to navigate to the directory using -c and passing in a cd but it exits out of interactive... guess I'll keep on chugging along

Comment: And the `-w` option?

Comment: Not seeing that option. FML must be behind in docker versions.... Currently on 13.1... really need to upgrade. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start from some directory when inside a container, use `-w` or `--workdir` option:

```
docker exec -it -w /blah/blah/blah/logs/ jboss bash
```

If that option is missing and you want to execute a command before navigating to shell, the simplest there is:

```
# Don't in case of strange path!
docker exec -it jboss bash -c "cd /blah/blah/blah/logs/ && bash"
# Better pass properly quoted argument in case of strange paths:
docker exec -it jboss bash -c 'cd "$1" && bash' -- "/blah/blah/blah/logs/"
docker exec -it jboss bash -c 'cd '"$(printf "%q" "/blah/blah/blah/logs/")"' && bash'
```