# How to open non integrated terminal window from vscode extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am developing an extension for Visual Studio Code. I need to open a terminal window and run some command there (One after another finishes). Same as Terminal.sendText but not in integrated terminal. Is there a way to do that?

**Update**

The closest I've got is using:

```js
const childProcess = spawn('node', ['--version'],{
    shell: true,
    detached: true,
    windowsHide: false
});
```

And the problem is it closes automatically

Comment: If you wan't to run multiple commands inline, you can use `&` symbol, like `echo yes & echo no` and if you wan't the next one only to run if the first one successful you can use `&&`

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly run the machine's terminal application and specify a command to run, like with `mate-terminal`, `-e` option. You could then run bash with certain startup commands [How to invoke bash, run commands inside the new shell, and then give control back to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/how-to-invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-the-new-shell-and-then-give-control-bac)

Comment: A example of that might be `mate-terminal -e "bash -c \"bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; ping google.com')\""` it's pretty crude, but I think you understand what I mean. it's just hard because there is a lot of terminal programs out there with different flags

Comment: Umm, sorry I can't understand this clearly. Run this command in the integrated terminal? And vscode extension can be used in all operating systems, what'll be the solution for those?

Comment: what part don't you understand? you will need to execute this command, also im not very sure of any command that's cross platform that runs a specific command in terminal, you will just need to add support for all the platforms manually. I know of `x-terminal-emulator` for debain that runs the default terminal application and takes a -e flag too.

Comment: Actually I expected if vscode extension api provides some function to make the task easier. And I've updated the question.

Comment: I would not think so, this is quite a random thing. but I have not used the vscode extension api before so I am not sure.

Comment: I took a quick glance over the vscode api and I saw nothing about opening a external terminal. why would you need this btw?

Comment: I know of a sublime extension https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal/ that can open a terminal in almost any os, so it is certainly possible, and I found this module that has support for quite a few operating systems https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-term