# How do I use `python -i 'script.py'` without closing terminal window after quitting interpreter?

Tags: python, linux

How do I use `python -i 'script.py'` without closing terminal window after quitting the script in interactive mode on Linux?

I want to return to terminal bash environment without closing the terminal window when I just quit the interpreter environment.

I use the following command inside a .desktop file in exec= session to launch the python script by an icon or shortcut.

```bash
gnome-terminal --full-screen -- python3 -i "path/to/script.py"
```

Comment: Python does not quit the interactive interpreter unless your script calls the built-in `exit()` or `sys.exit()`, which it should probably not.

Comment: Yes, you are right! What I am asking is a different question as a matter of fact, I want to return to terminal bash environment without closing the window when I just quit the interpreter environment. Sorry about my English, no native speaker here.

Comment: If you launch the Python process from an interactive shell, python should have no means, besides invoking *kill* to close the parent shell session. Please provide detailed steps how you start the terminal session and the python script.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention a important detail, because the command that follows, **gnome-terminal --full-screen -- python3 -i "path/to/script.py"**, is inside a .desktop file in exec= session to launch the python script by an icon or shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, you launch the `gnome-terminal` with python as the main process. Per default, `gnome-terminal` closes itself, if the shell process, in your case `python`, exits. You have two options.

## Modify the beahviour of `gnome-terminal`

In the settings for `gnome-terminal` navigate to your used profile (left sidebar), then to the 4th tab (named something like *Command*). In the bottom drowpdown menu (named something like *When command exits*) you can set gnome-terminal to keep running when the command exits.

However, this is most likely not what you want, since you'll be left with a non-functional terminal window **without a running shell**.

## Wrap your command in a shell process

If you want an interactive shell after python exits, you need to start one in the first place. To make it fall back to a shell, you can tell it to execute the shell again, after python exits:

```py
gnome-terminal --full-screen -- /bin/bash -c "python3 -i path/to/script.py; bash"
```

See also: [How to invoke bash, run commands inside the new shell, and then give control back to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/how-to-invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-the-new-shell-and-then-give-control-bac)

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works as expected.