# VSCode: How to open two terminals on startup with different directories

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

I want on startup (on folder open) two terminals.
These should start with different directories and should be in split mode. Is this possible?
I have this currently in `tasks.json`

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": false,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "showReuseMessage": true
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Create terminals",
            "dependsOn": [
                "First",
                "Second"
            ],
            // Mark as the default build task so cmd/ctrl+shift+b will create them
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            // Try start the task on folder open
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            }
        },
        {
            // The name that shows up in terminal tab
            "label": "First",
            // The task will launch a shell
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/bin/bash; cd /var/fpwork/",
            // Set the shell type
            // Mark as a background task to avoid the spinner animation on the terminal tab
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": [],
            // Create the tasks in a terminal group
            "presentation": {
                "group": "my-group"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Second",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/bin/bash; cd /var/",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "presentation": {
                "group": "my-group"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This opens two terminals in split mode, but how can I specify different folders for them?
The lines

```
"command": "/bin/bash; cd /var/fpwork/"
```

and

```
"command": "/bin/bash; cd /var/"
```

just seem to ignore the `cd` command. How to specify the terminal folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that worked for me is

```
"command": "/bin/bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; cd /var')"
```

See [How to invoke bash, run commands inside the new shell, and then give control back to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/how-to-invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-the-new-shell-and-then-give-control-bac)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following setting:

```json
"options": {
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior