# open bash subshell in specified directory

Tags: bash

When I run the `bash` command it opens a new subshell in the current directory.  Is there a way to open the new bash shell in a different directory?

This is what it does:

```
$ pwd
/original/location
$ bash
$ pwd
/original/location
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
$ pwd
/original/location
$ bash "some magic command to start it in a /another/location"
$ pwd
/another/location
$ exit
$ pwd
/original/location
```

**EDIT**
I also want it so that when I exit the subshell I return to the original location

Comment: `(cd /another/location && bash)`

Comment: @Thomas that works, can you put it in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: See [How to invoke bash, run commands inside the new shell, and then give control back to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7120426/4154375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `cd` to the directory before you start the subshell. To avoid changing directory in the parent shell, use parentheses to limit the change to a(nother) subshell:

```
(cd /another/location && bash)
```